# Getting Problem in converting to apk of a newly built React native application

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

I am facing this problem after doing all the steps mentioned in the RN guide but getting this problem after the command `./gradlew assembleRelease`. First i did was generating the keystore file using the command on RN docs and then pasted the file in android/app then updated build.gradle and gradle.properties and then ran the command `./gradlew clean` and then `./gradlew assembleRelease`

This is showing that there are deprecated files in the gradle but I cant figure them out. Please help

````
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:2545:18: warning: the variable "DebuggerInternal" was not declared in function "__shouldPauseOnThrow"                                                                        
          typeof DebuggerInternal !== 'undefined' &&
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:6203:7: warning: the variable "setTimeout" was not declared in function "logCapturedError"
      setTimeout(function () {```
      ^~~~~~~~~~
```android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:4172:108: warning: the variable "nativeFabricUIManager" was not declared in function "onChange"
...lInstanceHandle ? (from && nativeFabricUIManager.setIsJSResponder(from.sta...
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:4784:21: warning: the variable "clearTimeout" was not declared in anonymous function " 114#"
    cancelTimeout = clearTimeout;```
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:8534:30: warning: the variable "__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__" was not declared in anonymous function " 114#"
  if ("undefined" !== typeof __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__) {
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:10903:5: warning: the variable "setImmediate" was not declared in function "handleResolved"
    setImmediate(function () {
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:15187:12: warning: the variable "fetch" was not declared in anonymous function " 351#"
    fetch: fetch,
           ^~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:15188:14: warning: the variable "Headers" was not declared in anonymous function " 351#"
    Headers: Headers,
             ^~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:15189:14: warning: the variable "Request" was not declared in anonymous function " 351#"
    Request: Request,
             ^~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:15190:15: warning: the variable "Response" was not declared in anonymous function " 351#"
    Response: Response
              ^~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:15347:24: warning: the variable "FileReader" was not declared in function "readBlobAsArrayBuffer"
      var reader = new FileReader();
                       ^~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:15398:36: warning: the variable "Blob" was not declared in anonymous function " 362#"
        } else if (support.blob && Blob.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body)) {
                                   ^~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:15400:40: warning: the variable "FormData" was not declared in anonymous function " 362#"
        } else if (support.formData && FormData.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body)) {
                                       ^~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:15402:44: warning: the variable "URLSearchParams" was not declared in anonymous function " 362#"
...e if (support.searchParams && URLSearchParams.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body...
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:15521:26: warning: the variable "AbortController" was not declared in anonymous function " 368#"
          var ctrl = new AbortController();```
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:15655:23: warning: the variable "XMLHttpRequest" was not declared in anonymous function " 372#"
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:15200:71: warning: the variable "self" was not declared in anonymous function " 354#"
...undefined' && globalThis || typeof self !== 'undefined' && self ||
                                      ^~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:25801:27: warning: the variable "performance" was not declared in anonymous function " 676#"
  if ("object" === typeof performance && "function" === typeof performance.no...
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:25824:26: warning: the variable "navigator" was not declared in anonymous function " 676#"
  "undefined" !== typeof navigator && undefined !== navigator.scheduling && u...
                         ^~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:25934:37: warning: the variable "MessageChannel" was not declared in anonymous function " 676#"
  };else if ("undefined" !== typeof MessageChannel) {
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:25949:34: warning: the variable "nativeRuntimeScheduler" was not declared in anonymous function " 676#"
... = "undefined" !== typeof nativeRuntimeScheduler ? nativeRuntimeScheduler....
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:35242:34: warning: the variable "requestAnimationFrame" was not declared in function "start 9#"
...    this._animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(this.onUpdate.bind(this));
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:59674:20: warning: the variable "URL" was not declared in function "createURL"
        return new URL(createHref(to), "http://localhost");
                   ^~~
android\app\build\generated\assets\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\index.android.bundle:60003:30: warning: the variable "DOMException" was not declared in function "push 4#"
        if (error instanceof DOMException && error.name === "DataCloneError") {```

I tried removing packages, and  also created a fresh project and try to make its apk but got the same problem. 
If you know about this problem please help
````